# Can one use lando.dev for a production environment?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

OpenSource community developed free [lando.dev](https://lando.dev) looks great for a local development platform on one's own machine. I'm certainly looking to evaluate it for my own setup.

But, given there are benefits in having a development environment that matches production, if one is using [lando.dev](https://lando.dev) in development, then could one use it in production.

Sure, one might want to go on to use Kubernetes in production, but perhaps this is more than what one needs in the early stages of a project and therefore lando.dev is more suitable and more accessible.

Comment: probably yes but you will never know if you don't test it or see the big issue. Did you try helm

Comment: +1 thank you @pioupiou what do you mean by "the big issue" here? I will try it out for sure, but wondered about other folks' experience of it. Not tried [helm](https://helm.sh/) yet.

Comment: Sorry bug issues typo :)

Comment: +1 ah got you. Thank you @pioupiou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "the horses mouth":

https://twitter.com/DustinLeblanc/status/1220351066178510848

> We don't recommend Lando in production. The container images we use
>   aren't optimized for that and we don't test an open-to-the-internet
>   scenario. It's exclusively meant for local dev